# How to replace a substring with open parentheses (

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace

I am a Regex newbie and trying to implement Regex to replace a matching pattern in a string only when it has a ( - open parentheses using Javascript. for example if I have a string

```
IN(INTERM_LEVEL_IN + (int)X_ID)
```

I would only like to highlight the first IN( in the string. Not the INTERM_LEVEL_IN (2 ins here) and the int.

What is the Regex to accomplish this?

Comment: This has nothing to do with jQuery.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried which highlighted to wrong parts as well.

Answer (score 2):

To match the opening bracket you just need to escape it: `IN\(`.

For instance, running this in Firebug console:

`enter code here`"IN(INTERM_LEVEL_IN + (int)X_ID)".replace(/(IN()/, 'test');`

Will result in:

```
>>> "IN(INTERM_LEVEL_IN + (int)X_ID)".replace(/(IN\()/, 'test');
"testINTERM_LEVEL_IN + (int)X_ID)"
```

Comment: Thanks for answering my question! I think if I was replacing once in the string it works!! how to implement a regex with a global replace
ptrnX=  '/(IN\()/';
TempText.replace(new RegExp(ptrnX,'g'),"test")

Comment: Don't forget your backslash to escape the opening bracket after IN

Answer (score 1):

Parenthesis in regular expressions have a special meaning (sub-capture groups), so when you want them to be interpreted literally you have to escape them by with a `\` before them. The regular expression `IN\(` would match the string `IN(`.

Answer (score 1):

The following should only match IN( at the beginning of a line:

```
/^IN\(/
```

The following would match IN( that is not preceded by any alphanumeric character or underscore:

```
/[a-zA-Z0-9_]IN\(/
```

And finally, the following would match any instance of IN( no matter what precedes it:

```
/IN\(/
```

So, take your pick.  If you're interested in learning more about regex, here's a good tutorial: http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use just regular old Javascript for regex, a simple `IN\(` would work for the example you gave ([see here](http://rubular.com/r/GKT7Fh9Llg)), but I suspect your situation is more complicated than that. In which case, you need to define *exactly* what you are trying to match and what you don't want to match.